# Checking if user is added to application

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

How can I check if user is part of application? Application is using Active Directory for managing users. I thought that the following snippet will show me if user is added to application:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(baseURL, authenticationProvider, httpProvider = null);

var isAdded = await graphClient
                    .Users["username@domain.com"]
                    .Request()
                    .GetAsync();
```

But it works for every Active Directory member and I want it to work only for my application members. How can I achieve this?

Comment: How does a user become part of your application, do you store it in a database?

Comment: He is added in portal.azure to the application's user group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this code can help you. If you have a asp.net page, in the log in page after you authenticate the user you can add this code to check if the user has a role later:

```
            //Adds the user to the context
            var Identity = new GenericIdentity("Username", "Ldap");
            var principal = new GenericPrincipal(Identity, roles);
            HttpContext.User = principal;
```

The to check if the user is authenticated or if he is on a specific role :

```
            //checks if the user is is authenticated
            if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                //checks if the user has a role
                if (User.IsInRole("user"))
                {

                }
            }
```